# ASP.NET MVC SiteMap provider -Razor

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have downloaded the MVC SiteMap Provider from codeplex  and Registered the same. In my views I am using Razor(.cshtml) to display.

I have a menu with all buttons in my Views folder.  How do I use the  MVC sitemap to display few buttons in the Views and hide the others based on the roles .

I could not find any examples on How to configure the hiding and showing?

steps would be more helpful, what to do where?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Title, description and roles are retrieved from the xml node and used to create the site map node. The Roles attribute enables the security trimming feature, which hides all nodes that are not accessible to the user based on his or her roles.

More info @ http://www.webpirates.nl/webpirates/robin-van-der-knaap/29-aspnet-mvc-site-map